# Why does this code stop reading the lines on my file with Scanner? (java)

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I have this java code that stops Scanning my .txt file, weird enough this only happens on my PC, I have classmates that use their laptops or lab PCs, and they work correctly even though the code are exactly the same, more detail on the image:

```
package lab07;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rankings {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner archivo = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\adxlm\\Downloads\\IMDB.txt"));
        System.out.print("Enter the quantity of rankings: ");
        // int nrorankings = input.nextInt();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println(archivo.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

It stops printing at line 24, as shown:

```
20  8.6 612312  City of God (2002)
21  8.6 1065032 Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope  (1977)
22  8.6 1206250 Se7en   (1995)
23  8.6 403913  Avengers: Infinity War  (2018)
24  8
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at lab07.peliculas.main(peliculas.java:12)
```

This is the .txt file at that point *https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hCjp.jpg*

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Check your local IMDB copy in notepad to see what's on line 24.

Answer (score 0):

You should use BufferReader instead of Scanner:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    BufferedReader archivo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\adxlm\\Downloads\\IMDB.txt"));
    System.out.print("Enter the quantity of rankings: ");

    try {
        String line = archivo.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = archivo.readLine();
        }
        archivo.close();
    } catch (
            IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```